# Excel Swap Column of number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, swap

I am creating an excel file to swap excel columns which contains the number corresponding to the ASCII character such as low letter, upper letter, number, special characters.

Here is the original table and the corresponding letter to the number

```
 A B C D E F G H
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I want to swap each of the cell to the end. Meaning I need to swap 1 to 8. 2 to 7. 3 to 6.

```
 A B C D E F G H
 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

I would want to use the excel function to do this. Is there a way to achieve this? I have 156 columns.

what about this method.

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  4
E  5
F  6
G  7
H  8
```

Comment: Which Excel version are you using? Are all numbers in a given and consecutive order?

Comment: yes they are in a consecutive order. Excel office365

Comment: Then it's even simpler: `=SORT(A2:H2,,-1,1)`

Comment: It does not work

Comment: Are you saying that I need to implement the sort function and the same cell number in every column?

Comment: The `SORT` function suggested by @JvdV is a *spill over* formula. Thus you only have to put it in one cell, e.g. `J2` and it will spill over to the right as far as necessary.

Comment: You could also try `=OFFSET($A$2,0,COLUMNS(A2:H2) - 1 - (COLUMN()-COLUMN($J$2)))` placed in `J2` with your sample data in `A1:H2`. But this would have to be copied to the right as far as necessary.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot og the problems you are facing with the `SORT` function.

Comment: Hi sorry it worked. I mistake the letter of the column

Comment: If I use the other way around like show the number in the horizontal, it does not work

Comment: In case of the `SORT` function, you will have to wrap it in `TRANSPOSE` to receive the results in a vertical range, while the source is in a horizontal range. In case of the `OFFSET` solution, you will have to use `ROW(S)` instead of `COLUMN(S)` and put the pieces in the right position of the `OFFSET` formula.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your data is always ordered then sorting would work.

But let's assume your data is not always alphabetically or numerically sortable, you can use a formula to reverse an unsorted list:

| - | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 3 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |

Rows 1 and 2 are your original data.  Row 3 is the reversing formula.

Add the formula below into cell A3

```
=INDEX($A$2:$G$2, COLUMNS(A2:$G$2))
```

Note (important) that the first Range of the INDEX is absolute `$A$2:$G$2`, but the only the last value of the columns range is absolute A2:`$G$2` (no dollars)

Either drag cell A3 across to H3 or copy cell A3 and paste over B3:H3

This has an advantage over plain sorting in that it can reverse unsorted lists for you.